# How to determine what gradle command was running

Tags: gradle

I want to measure time of execution for different gradle command so I have to know what exactly command was run.

For example when I execute from terminal

```
./gradlew clean
```

If I execute

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

desired result is "assembleDebug"

I know I can get list of tasks with `project.tasks`, but it will give me only list of tasks which my command will execute, without command that started them all.

Is there any option to determine that "first" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how that should work

```
project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames
```

gives list of task names. For example if I run **multiple** commands like

```
./gradlew app:clean app:cleanBuildCache
```

it will contain both commands.

Is is possible to cast it for string directly

```
project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.toString()
```

So I will have

> [app:clean, app:cleanBuildCache]

With **single** command like

```
./gradlew app:clean
```

I receive

> [app:clean]

and that was what I searched for